# What's the joint and conditional distribution of two independent random variables with geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem in my homework:

[image]

Here is my attempt of solution:

[image]

I'm particularly afraid of having messed things up when I was calculating the $P(X>Y)$ part. I didn't want to use the convolution formula since I think it's that nat intuitive. Is my reasoning and solution right? Any insights are helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The joint pdf $\varphi(x,y)$  of independent random variables is the product of their pdf under the form $f(x)g(y)$. Thus the marginals are... $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. After, you can apply it to any distribution, geometric or not...

Comment: There was no reason for a summation for $Pr(X\lt Y)$ since the symmetry argument is nicer.  Everything is done correctly, the conditional distribution in b) is indeed uniform.

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag. When in doubt, please avail yourself of the tag summaries in choosing tags.